# How to unit test public behavior dependent on private state?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need to unit test a public interface method of a class, but the defined behavior is dependent on a private state variable.  Something like this:

```
private enum _state;

public void Connect()
{
    if (_state == AlreadyConnected)
        throw Exception;

    (... do more things ...)
}
```

In this case I want to ensure the proper exception is thrown if the method is called when the state is already a specific value, but how can I set this up if the state field is private?

Comment: Test the public behaviour: connect once, then assert that calling connect again will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case private state represents the result of actions performed on entity and its reaction on the actions.
So, test will look like:

```
[Test]
public void Connect_throws_exception_if_already_connected()
{
       var foo = new Foo();
       foo.Connect();


       Exception thrownExc = null;

       try
       {
            foo.Connect();
       }
       catch(InvalidOperationException exc)
       {
           thrownExc = exc;
       }

       Assert.IsNotNull(thrownExc, "It was expected to get exception on 2nd connect attempt, but nothing were thrown.");
}
```

Comment: You can also use [`[ExpectedException]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx)

Comment: @Blorgbeard, yes, I can. But to be honest I don't like it much, because attribute covers the whole unit test(so it will pass no matter what line will throw the exc). That's why I prefer `XUnit` or `FluentAssertions` frameworks - they both have capabilities of asserting if specified action throws exc(like `Action a = ()=>foo.Connect(); a.ShouldThrow<InvalidException>();`). And when working with `mstest` I usuall end up with similar manually written helpers.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I was thinking about this the wrong way.  Thanks for the response.